# Regex match the entire string

Tags: c++, regex

I'm  attempting to use regex to match an entire string, but I'm getting some odd results.

The idea is to match an IP address string, or, a partially typed IP address string.

I.e. `23.44` would be allowed as it's partially typed

`244.655.` would not be allowed as 655 is too high.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string str1 = "23.4f";
    std::string str2 = "234.233.12";
    std::string str3 = "fdfdf";
    std::string str4 = "f233.21.3";

    std::regex reg("^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])(\.((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])(\.((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])(\.((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]))?)?)?)?)?)?$",std::regex::ECMAScript|std::regex::optimize);

    if(std::regex_match(str1,reg))
        std::cout << "string 1 matches" << std::endl;

    if(std::regex_match(str2,reg))
        std::cout << "string 2 matches" << std::endl;

    if(std::regex_match(str3,reg))
        std::cout << "string 3 matches" << std::endl;

    if(std::regex_match(str4,reg))
        std::cout << "string 4 matches" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output is

```
string 1 matches
string 2 matches
```

I assume it's got a match on the first part of `str1` but I thought firstly that `regex_match` had to match the entire string and then the added inclusion of the string boundaries in the regex pattern would have ensured the whole thing matched.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `"\."` is a `.` that matches any char. Use `"\\."` or a raw string literal.

Comment: @DWR why would I do that when my number matching part is working?